# Installing django on dreamhost (help a newb out)

Tags: python, django, dreamhost

I'm trying to get django running on my dreahost account.  I've been trying to sort of use two tutorials at once: the one on the dreamhost wiki and the one in the django book.

I installed django using the script on the wiki page, but I ran into trouble immediately while trying to work through the django book.  It says:

> To start the server, change into your project directory (cd mysite), if you haven’t already, and run this command:
>
> python manage.py runserver
>
> This launches the server locally, on port 8000, accessible only to connections from your own computer. Now that it’s running, visit 127.0.0.1:8000 with your Web browser. You’ll see a “Welcome to Django” page shaded in a pleasant pastel blue. It worked!

Those instructions seem to assume that you're developing locally, not on a shared server.  Where the heck am I supposed to look for the "Welcome to Django" page after starting the server?  In my webroot?  No dice.

Anyway, I tried to blunder ahead through the django book to its hello world tutorial (chapter 3).  But once I've edited the view file and the URLconf, I don't get a nice clean "hello world" text.  Instead ([as you can see](http://wikiprofessor.org/hello/)) I get an "import error".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project assumes that 1) your app is called "mysite", and 2) `mysite` is a package, e.g. `mysite/__init__.py` exists. If either of those are false then correct your code and/or file structure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and learn Django via your server. Install it on your local computer, learn how it works, develop your project, and then install it on Dreamhost.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post and  am sure you have found the answer by now. I have solved this problem by using the command

```
python manage.py runserver mydomain.com:8080
```